# How to include inline content in pyjade

Tags: python, flask, pug, pyjade

I had the following code in my jade file:

```
a(href='{{url_for("browse_problem", problem_id=problem._id)}}')
```

I was trying to evaluate the url_for function and set the value as the href attribute, but the code above does not work. Can someone help me correct it?

Comment: I haven't used pyjade, but I'm guessing you're looking for: `a(href=url_for("browse_problem", problem_id=problem._id))`

Answer (score 4):

This bug is fixed in the new version 1.0 of [pyjade](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade).

Check it out!

This new code is totally compatible with the new version:

```
a(href=url_for("browse_problem", problem_id=problem._id))
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem myself by changing some code inside pyjade... Seems to be a bug when parsing content including 'class' or 'id'.

Comment: I'd love it if you could submit a patch for this on GitHub... https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade

Comment: @Roshambo I have a forked repo which solved this problem: https://github.com/dementrock/pyjade. However it may cause other problems (see https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/pyjade/pull/5)